# mysqli query succeeds but gives error number 0

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, stored-procedures

My apologies for being a slightly broader question then most like but i can't find any help throughout the internet for this. I'm working on a site where i am not in charge of the database (yes its very problematic) and i was told to use a stored procedure to insert data into a table.

The query is being run. It inserts the data into the table but something else is triggering the error.

My question is: Is there anything in this code that would trigger that error or is it something in the stored procedure? What can i do to test for it? Any suggestions at all? I can't figure out what the error number : 0 actually is.

I'm using codeigniter framework. Here's the code:

```
 public function addScopeContent () {
    $cn = '%';
    $gp = $this->input->post('group');
    $co = $this->input->post('company');
    $ci = $this->input->post('city');
    $dp = '%';

    if ($gp == 'BU000') {
        $gp = '%';
    }
    if ($co == 'CO000') {
        $co = '%';
    }
    if ($ci == 'CI000') {
        $ci = '%';
    }

    $location = $cn .'-'. $gp .'-'. $co .'-'. $ci .'-'. $dp;

    $query = $this->db->query('call rollout_systems_multiimport('. $this->session->userdata('scopeId') .', "'. $location .'")');
    if ($query) {
        redirect('discovery/addContent');
    }
}
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `rollout_systems_multiimport`(
  var_scope_id varchar(250),
  var_searchString varchar(250))
  BEGIN

  Insert into rollout_systems
  (`sys_name`, `sys_serial`, `eam_model`, `EOL_date`, `eam_user`, `scope_id`)
  select `ad_name`,`eam_Serial_Number`,`eam_Model`,`Model_EOL`,`ad_account`,var_scope_id
  from `disc_userpool` inner join `disc_systempool`
  on `ad_account` = `user_aurora_id`
  Where `disc_userpool`.`location_code` like var_searchString;
```

NOTE: I just tried changing the dbdriver in the database.php page from mysqli to mysql. It doesnt give an error anymore.

Comment: 1) what database are you using? (mysql?), 2) what access layer are you using? (PDO?)

Comment: phpmyadmin(?) and i have no idea...

Comment: Error code 0 with MySQL I think is a connection error.  Probably not your stored procedure.  Are you able to issue even a basic SELECT or SHOW statement?

Comment: Yeah, the entire site has tons of queries, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, ect.

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a DBMS, it's a frontend tool for MySQL

Comment: So any tips for how to fix it or what it might be?

Comment: Closed for not being a real question yet has a real answer that solved a real problem. hmmmm.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a [codeigniter mysql driver bug](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/181751/#860516), try using the [`simple_query`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html/) method.

Comment: Thank you! It works. I was at the point of just turning off errors cause technically the query was running anyway. Wish i could vote this up more then once